# Outer Joins of dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

[image: image of dataframes in an Excel sheet]

Need to join one main dataframe (`main_df`) in such a way that for a given primary data is not present in all others data frames (e.g. `vendor1_df`, `vendor2_df`) then row from main frame should not be returned.

Example is shown in Excel above. In the example, you will find org code 876 is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an inner join of `main_df` with the full outer join of the two vendor dataframes. This way, lines from `main_df` are kept if and only if there appear at least once in one of the vendor dataframes. In pseudo code: `main_df.inner_join(vendor1.full_join(vendor2))`.

In spark:

```py
# creating your data
vendor1_df = spark.createDataFrame([(123, 90, 45), (167, 45, 60)], ['Org_code', 'revenue', 'emp_code'])
vendor2_df = spark.createDataFrame([(456, 90, 45), (167, 450, 899)], ['Org_code', 'revenue', 'emp_code'])
main_df = spark.createDataFrame([(123, 'ABC'), (456, 'CDE'), (876, "egf"), (167, 'hnmm')], ['Org_code', 'Org_name'])

# renaming colunms
df1 = vendor1_df.select('Org_code', vendor1_df['revenue'].alias('v1_revenue'),  vendor1_df['emp_code'].alias('v1_emp_code'))
df2 = vendor2_df.select('Org_code', vendor2_df['revenue'].alias('v2_revenue'),  vendor2_df['emp_code'].alias('v2_emp_code'))

# and the result
all_vendors = df1.join(df2, ['Org_code'], 'full')
main_df.join(all_vendors, ['Org_code']).show()
```

```
+--------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|Org_code|Org_name|v1_revenue|v1_emp_code|v2_revenue|v2_emp_code|
+--------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|     123|     ABC|        90|         45|      null|       null|
|     456|     CDE|      null|       null|        90|         45|
|     167|    hnmm|        45|         60|       450|        899|
+--------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I like ANSI SQL.  I have been writing queries since the 1990s.  Therefore, lets you spark SQL.

```
#
# Create dataframes
#

df1 = spark.createDataFrame( [(123, 90, 45), (167, 45, 60)], ['Org_code', 'vendor1_revenue', 'vendor1_emp_code'] )
df2 = spark.createDataFrame( [(456, 90, 45), (167, 450, 899)], ['Org_code', 'vendor2_revenue', 'vendor2_emp_code'] )
df3 = spark.createDataFrame( [(123, 'ABC'), (456, 'CDE'), (876, "egf"), (167, 'hnmm')], ['Org_code', 'Org_name'] )
```

Make dataframes above and create temporary views below.

```
#
# Create views
#

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("vendor1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("vendor2")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("main")
```

Just use a left join since the main table is the driver.

```
%sql
select 
  m1.*,
  v1.vendor1_revenue,
  v1.vendor1_emp_code,
  v2.vendor2_revenue,
  v2.vendor2_emp_code
from main as m1 
left join vendor1 as v1 on m1.org_code = v1.org_code
left join vendor2 as v2 on m1.org_code = v2.org_code
where v1.org_code is not null or v2.org_code is not null
```

We just need to add a where clause that tosses out rows in which the main table does not match any vendors.

I keep on trying to promote Spark SQL since many technologist know ANSI SQL.

[image]

The expected result is in the above image.